# Compare the contents of all files inside a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory with multiple txt files, I need to compare the contents of each txt file and print the output as "Yay all files are same" else " Oops, File are not same"

```
cd tmp_dir
ls
abc.txt cde.txt fgh.txt ... xyz.txt

[ tmp_dir ]$ cat abc.txt
2022-08-01_20:14:36
[ tmp_dir ]$ cat def.txt
2022-08-01_07:40:29
[ tmp_dir ]$
```

How to loops through files and compare the contents

```
    for file in tmp_dir/*; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        cmp -s -- files # need to compare all the files under directory
    fi
    done
```

> Expected Output:

```
#If contents are same [Output should be in Green color]
Yay, all files are same

#If contents are not same [In red color]
Oops, Files are not the same
```

Comment: You don't need to compare every file to every other file, so maybe just compare file1 to flie2, file2 to file3, and so on. You can cheat by using sha1sum or md5sum or something to just compute the hashes and see how many distinct values you get

Comment: If you have `uniq` from GNU coreutils, this one-liner will list duplicated files: `find dir -type f -exec sha256sum {} + | sort | uniq -w64 -D` . If there is no output, then no duplicates. Replace `-w64` with `-w128` if you use `sha512sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a single pipeline by hashing all of the files and then counting how many unique hashes you get. If the answer is 1, all of the files are the same.

```
distinct_hashes="$(
    find dir/ -type f -exec sha512sum {} + |    # hash all files in `dir/`
        awk '{print $1}' |                      # strip file names from output
        sort -u |                               # remove duplicate hashes
        wc -l                                   # count distinct hashes
)"

case "$distinct_hashes" in
    0) echo "no files";;
    1) echo "all the same";;
    *) echo "not all the same";;
esac
```

Alternatively, you could use `cmp` as you tried, and it would be more efficient. You'll just have to manually loop over all of the files. Note that you don't have to compare all pairs of files, which would be *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>); you can keep it *O*(*n*) by comparing each file to one other.

```
first_file=
same=1

for file in dir/*; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue

    if [[ -z "$first_file" ]]; then
        first_file="$file"
    elif ! cmp -s "$file" "$first_file"; then
        same=0
        break
    fi
done

if [[ -z "$first_file" ]]; then
    echo "no files"
elif ((same)); then
    echo "all the same"
else
    echo "not all the same"
fi
```

<sub>Advanced shell scripters might point out the quotes in `distinct_hashes="$(...)"`, `case "$distinct_hashes"`, `[[ -f "$file" ]]`, `[[ -z "$first_file" ]]`, and `first_file="$file"` are unnecessary. I like to include optional quotes. Quoting variable expansions is a really important habit to develop and not everyone will know the intricacies of when they are and aren't required.</sub>

Comment: or replace the `awk/sort/uniq/wc` with `awk '{a[$1]} END {print length(a)}'` (assuming `GNU awk`)

Comment: Excellent idea. Doing it all in `awk` will be more efficient as it avoids extra pipelining and an O(n log n) sort. Of course the price you pay is it's harder to understand. More efficient or more readable? It's a tradeoff.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks for the solution, 2nd approach is best , and How to add green and red color to echo ouput  [green] echo "all the same"  and [red color] for echo "not all the same"

Comment: Printing colored text is a separate question. Please google it and post a new question if you can't find the answer.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Okay, Thanks for the detailed pointers and approcah